# Google chart query mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, charts

I have been trying json for transfer the information between php and javascript but doesn't work.
The query it's okay, i check it
The result of the query named "dia" is a date and "importe" is a number(float)

Any idea ?
Thanks for the help

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" > </script>
  
 </head>  
 <body>
   <div id="line_chart" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
  
     <?php
                            $consulta = "SELECT fecha as dia,SUM(importe) as importe FROM tfg.reservas WHERE fecha  < '2019-05-31' AND fecha > '2019-05-20' GROUP BY DAY(fecha) asc;";

    $json = array();   
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
 if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
      while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
          $dataRow = array(
              $fila['dia'],
              $fila['importe'],
              
          );
          array_push($json, $dataRow);
      }
  }

  $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
?>
     
     <script type="text/javascript">

   google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart()
   {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [{type: 'date', label: 'dia'}, {type: 'number', label: 'importe'}]
      ]);

      data.addRows(<?= $jsonstring ?>);

    var options = {
     title:'Sensors Data',
     legend:{position:'bottom'},
     chartArea:{width:'95%', height:'65%'}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to pass data from PHP to JS

Comment: I  have added JSON but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you explain what doesn't work?

Comment: the chart is not generated

Comment: check the browser's console (F12) for errors

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type mismatch. Value 2019-05-25 does not match type date in column index 0

Comment: I have put format: 'Yyyy-mm-dd', but doesn't work, comes out the same error Any idea?